# Get-MailboxExportRequest not returning any results

Tags: powershell, exchange-2016

I have created a mailbox export request on my Exchange 2016 environment to export a user's mailbox to a PST.

I am trying to run Get-MailboxExportRequest to see what the status of the export is.

Unfortunately, the command is returning no results. It is not erroring, or issuing any warnings and I am a member of the role granting access to the export commands.

I know the export is running as I can see the file size of the destination PST file changing.

The Exchange setup is two Exchange Servers running two DBs as part of a single DAG with one DB active on either server at a time. Both are running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter.

I have tried running the command from both Exchange servers and with command line args pointing to each of the two DCs in case that helped (it didn't). (-DomainController ).

I have tried with the -Status parameter with no luck and I have tried with and without specifying a mailbox.

Can anyone suggest to me what I need to do in order to get it to show me the status of my export(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Is your account in a [role group](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj657480(v=exchg.160).aspx) that has the *Mailbox Import Export* role? If you were able to use the `New-MailboxExportRequest` cmdlet with this account, [`Get-MailboxExportRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607479(v=exchg.160).aspx) should also work.

> This cmdlet is available only in the Mailbox Import Export role, and
>   by default, that role isn't assigned to a role group. To use this
>   cmdlet, you need to add the Mailbox Import Export role to a role group
>   (for example, to the Organization Management role group).

Comment: Yes, I included in the question that I was a member of the role. Had I not been I wouldn't even have been able to see the command and so would be getting an error rather than nothing.